# How to sign my android project in jenkins?

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

[image]I am using Jenkins where I use `BUILD --> INVOKE ANTS --> TARGETS --> clean debug` to get a **debug build (apk)** from it. Now I want to get a **signed apk** from jenkins. I have added this settings in `BUILD --> INVOKE ANTS --> TARGETS --> clean release`. I know that this one is not enough to get a signed apk build out from the jenkins. What else I should add to get a **signed APK**? Please help me on this. Also give a me a detailed explanation because I am new to this.

These are the parameters I have added.

[image: This is the error message for every build run in jenkin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jenkins [documentation](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/getting-started-building-android-apps-hudson):

> Running the build in Hudson
>   This part is easy: create a new freestyle job and let it be build with ant. The targets that we want to execute are clean release. **Release will compile, package and sign your apk**. Now to get this working right, some custom properties should be set (use the Advanced button).
>
> sdk.dir=/Users/hugo/Code/android-sdk-mac
>
> target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:7
>
> key.store=certs/rd-release.keystore key.alias=rainydays
>
> key.store.password=thisisnotmypassword
>
> key.alias.password=thisisnotmypassword
>
> The sdk.dir should point to the Android SDK root on your Hudson node. In my case I'm running Hudson locally on my machine. The target property refers to the SDK we want to use as mentioned earlier. The *key.** properties are related to signing of the apk. My strategy is to have a separate key store and private key for each application that I develop. I also check that keystore in to SVN. I also archive the **-release.apk* artifact so that I can download the latest release apk directly from Hudson. After completing these steps, you should be able to build your Android app with Hudson.

You can check more configurations in the documentation.

Comment: I have already referred this documentation and I followed the same. But still I get this error:  **E:\Project_Stuffs\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:1132: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Project_Stuffs\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:1144: E:\Temp\Jenkins\Builds\Sample-Project\certs\sample-release.keystore (The system cannot find the path specified)

Total time: 7 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE**